# Crossbar.io - Restrict user to subscribe to only two topics

Tags: autobahn, wamp-protocol, crossbar, autobahnws

I had seen in the Crossbar.io documentation, that we can set role to publish only to specific topic. But how can I set a role to publish exactly matching two topics rather than pattern based matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a configuration like this (see [Static Authorization](http://crossbar.io/docs/Authorization/) in the docs):

```
"realms": [
   {
      "name": "realm1",
      "roles": [
         {
            "name": "role1",
            "permissions": [
               {
                  "uri": "com.example.topic1",
                  "publish": true
               },
               {
                  "uri": "com.example.topic2",
                  "publish": true
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```